# java.lang.NullPointerException between 2 activities

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities and I'm using the second one to access this function from the first one, which gives me the error. The error comes from the 3rd line.

```
for(i = 0; i < linii; i++)
    {
            siruri[i] = new TableRow(this); //this line causes the error
        TableLayout.LayoutParams detalii = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
    }
```

This is the full log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:94)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3568)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:469)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:168)
        at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:61)
        at com.example.cool.appname.MainActivity.creeare(MainActivity.java:65)
        at com.example.cool.appname.MainActivity.redim(MainActivity.java:254)
        at com.example.cool.appname.Matrice2Activity.Egal(Matrice2Activity.java:225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If it's relevant, this is how I make an intent to start MainActivity from the second one:

```
Intent incercare = new Intent(Matrice2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
    incercare.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(incercare);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: pls add stack trace to original post.

Comment: What is on the 65 line of MainActivity?

Comment: That is the 3rd line in this code, I had to delete the rest to be able to edit it.

Comment: please take a look at my answer.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `TableRow(this)` would throw a NPE, so I'm guessing that `siruri` is null.

Comment: If siruri is null, shouldn't this code assign a value to it?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Check the stacktrace, it comes from `new TableRow(this)`.

Comment: Obviously yet another premature Context usage (or `new ActivityDerivedClass()` ) ... please, learn about activitie's lifecycle

Comment: @Vali79 No, it wouldn't.  But I think @Tom and @Selvin are right.  If the code you showed us were called from outside a lifecycle method, or in a situation where `this` does not refer to a running activity, the `Context` might not be fully initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `Matrice2Activity` is running at the moment, which means that your `MainActivity` is paused or even stopped. And you are creating `TableRow` with the paused or stopped activity as parameter. I suspect it is not legal to create a any `View` object by referencing activity that is not running.

And for sure it is not correct to call method of one activity from another activity. Because Android takes care of creating and destroying them and nothing can guarantee you that the other activity will be there. (Imagine you are in `Matrice2Activity` activity, your application gets to the background, then gets completely stopped because of lack of resources, and then user wants to switch back, the application gets restarted and `Matrice2Activity` gets recreated, but no instance of `MainActivity` will even exist in the program at that point!) You must have already done something hackish to get the reference of the `MainActivity` instance inside `Matrice2Activity`.

The proper way of returning some information from activity to previous activity is by starting the activity with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and then giving back result with [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29). That way you can forward `Bundle` with any data in both ways.

PS: It is tedious and looks ineffective to forward around data this way. Sometimes it's better to pack more functionality inside one activity and just shuffle views around.

Comment: *hackish* :) ... most likely `new MainActivity()`

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the code and used startActivityForResult() and now it works.

Comment: Great. Best way to thank is with upvote and/or accepting the answer. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Try  this:

Write an Activity1 argument for your function in Activity2 and then add it to the line that make the NullPointerException. just like:

```
public function activity2Function(Activity1 activity1) {
    siruri[i] = new TableRow(activity1);
}
```

Comment: Oh come on @Tom , it is [obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)

Comment: @Selvin Obvious that OP would still pass `this` to `activity2Function` and therefore run into the same problem? Yes, I think so too.